# Cannot run program "Composer"

Tags: composer-php, symfony

I'm working with Symfony 3. I used FOSCommentBundle on my project, it uses `assetic-bundle` which is not supported by Symfony 3. I tried running the command `composer require symfony/assetic-bundle`
but I keep getting:

> Cannot run program(in directory "C:\wamp\www\myProject") "composer"CreateProcess error=2".

Ps: I'm a beginner

```
{
"name": "symfony/symfony",
"type": "library",
"description": "The Symfony PHP framework",
"keywords": ["framework"],
"homepage": "https://symfony.com",
"license": "MIT",
"authors": [
    {
        "name": "Fabien Potencier",
        "email": "fabien@symfony.com"
    },
    {
        "name": "Symfony Community",
        "homepage": "https://symfony.com/contributors"
    }
],
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.5.9",
    "doctrine/common": "~2.4",
    "twig/twig": "~1.28|~2.0",
    "psr/cache": "~1.0",
    "psr/log": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-intl-icu": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-mbstring": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-php56": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-php70": "~1.0",
    "symfony/polyfill-util": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2"
},
"replace": {
    "symfony/asset": "self.version",
    "symfony/browser-kit": "self.version",
    "symfony/cache": "self.version",
    "symfony/class-loader": "self.version",
    "symfony/config": "self.version",
    "symfony/console": "self.version",
    "symfony/css-selector": "self.version",
    "symfony/dependency-injection": "self.version",
    "symfony/debug": "self.version",
    "symfony/debug-bundle": "self.version",
    "symfony/doctrine-bridge": "self.version",
    "symfony/dom-crawler": "self.version",
    "symfony/event-dispatcher": "self.version",
    "symfony/expression-language": "self.version",
    "symfony/filesystem": "self.version",
    "symfony/finder": "self.version",
    "symfony/form": "self.version",
    "symfony/framework-bundle": "self.version",
    "symfony/http-foundation": "self.version",
    "symfony/http-kernel": "self.version",
    "symfony/inflector": "self.version",
    "symfony/intl": "self.version",
    "symfony/ldap": "self.version",
    "symfony/monolog-bridge": "self.version",
    "symfony/options-resolver": "self.version",
    "symfony/process": "self.version",
    "symfony/property-access": "self.version",
    "symfony/property-info": "self.version",
    "symfony/proxy-manager-bridge": "self.version",
    "symfony/routing": "self.version",
    "symfony/security": "self.version",
    "symfony/security-core": "self.version",
    "symfony/security-csrf": "self.version",
    "symfony/security-guard": "self.version",
    "symfony/security-http": "self.version",
    "symfony/security-bundle": "self.version",
    "symfony/serializer": "self.version",
    "symfony/stopwatch": "self.version",
    "symfony/templating": "self.version",
    "symfony/translation": "self.version",
    "symfony/twig-bridge": "self.version",
    "symfony/twig-bundle": "self.version",
    "symfony/validator": "self.version",
    "symfony/var-dumper": "self.version",
    "symfony/web-profiler-bundle": "self.version",
    "symfony/yaml": "self.version"
},
"require-dev": {
    "cache/integration-tests": "dev-master",
    "doctrine/cache": "~1.6",
    "doctrine/data-fixtures": "1.0.*",
    "doctrine/dbal": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "~2.4,>=2.4.5",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.4",
    "monolog/monolog": "~1.11",
    "ocramius/proxy-manager": "~0.4|~1.0|~2.0",
    "predis/predis": "~1.0",
    "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "~3.2",
    "egulias/email-validator": "~1.2,>=1.2.1",
    "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "~1.1",
    "symfony/security-acl": "~2.8|~3.0",
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "^3.0"
},
"conflict": {
    "phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock": "<3.0",
    "phpdocumentor/type-resolver": "<0.2.0"
},
"provide": {
    "psr/cache-implementation": "1.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Symfony\\Bridge\\Doctrine\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Doctrine/",
        "Symfony\\Bridge\\Monolog\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Monolog/",
        "Symfony\\Bridge\\ProxyManager\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/ProxyManager/",
        "Symfony\\Bridge\\Swiftmailer\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Swiftmailer/",
        "Symfony\\Bridge\\Twig\\": "src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/",
        "Symfony\\Bundle\\": "src/Symfony/Bundle/",
        "Symfony\\Component\\": "src/Symfony/Component/"
    },
    "classmap": [
        "src/Symfony/Component/Intl/Resources/stubs"
    ],
    "exclude-from-classmap": [
        "**/Tests/"
    ]
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"extra": {
    "branch-alias": {
        "dev-master": "3.1-dev"
    }
}
```

When I run `composer require symfony/assetic-bundle -vvv` this is what I get:

> Cannot run program "composer" (in directory "C:\wamp\www\myProject"): CreateProcess error=2, 
>   The specified file can not be found

Comment: I have worked on Symfony3 and it's possible to use assetic-bundle. I don't think the error is caused by assetic-bundle. Could you give your composer.json file and the picture of your cmd after executing `composer require symfony/assetic-bundle -vvv` (please note, add `-vvv`, which means `very very verbose`) to get the details.

Comment: @RendyEkoPrastiyo I just did :)

Comment: your problem is about the `composer` program itself which is not found in your system when you run `composer bla bla bla`. If you want an easy way, you may download [composer.phar](https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar), copy it to your root project (C:\wamp\www\myProject), and you can use composer by calling `php composer.phar bla bla bla`.

Comment: I tried what you suggested, it didn't work. However I downloaded composer-Setup and configured composer globally on windows. That solved theproblem. Thank you for your help